# This async code seems to have to be executed like the synchrone code, is it really?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    //static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating factorial of 100 asynchronously...");
        //int result = await Task.Run(() => fibo(30));
        int result = fibo(30);
        Console.WriteLine($"Factorial of 100 = {result}");

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int fibo(int n)
    {
        int result = 1;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}



using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class Program
{
    static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating factorial of 100 asynchronously...");
        int result = await Task.Run(() => fibo(30));
        Console.WriteLine($"Factorial of 100 = {result}");

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int fibo(int n)
    {
        int result = 1;
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        {

            result *= i;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In both case this is what is returned

> Calculating factorial of 100 asynchronously...

> Factorial of 100 = 0

> Press Enter to exit...

What is the interest of using asyncrone in this fall. I'm waiting 5 seconds in both cases

Comment: _"What is the interest of using asyncrone in this fall"_ - nothing, you're doing CPU-bound work, not waiting on I/O while freeing up a thread to do other work. async does not magically make your code faster nor paralellizes it; it just waits for work to finish without tying up a CPU thread.

Comment: In the first case you are directly calling a method that takes 5s, in the second case you are starting a separate task to call a method that takes 5s and then using `await` to wait for the task to complete. These will of course both take 5s.

Answer (score -1):

Synchronous case, program will sleep about 20secs.

```
static void Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating factorial of 100 asynchronously...");

        int result = fibo(39);
        int result2 = fibo(39);
        int result3 = fibo(39);
        int result4 = fibo(39);
        Console.WriteLine($"Factorial of 100 = {result}");

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Asynchronous case, program will sleep about only 5secs.

```
 static async Task Main()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Calculating factorial of 100 asynchronously...");
        

        var result = Task.Run(() => fibo(30));
        var result2 = Task.Run(() => fibo(30));
        var result3 = Task.Run(() => fibo(30));
        var result4 = Task.Run(() => fibo(30));

        var tasks = new List<Task<int>>();
        tasks.Add(result);
        tasks.Add(result2);
        tasks.Add(result3);
        tasks.Add(result4);
        Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

        Console.WriteLine($"Factorial of 100 = ");

        Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Question is not about parallelization, but about `async`.

Comment: @CodeCaster I just think this is an interesting example to demonstrate the advantage of asynchronous code